# how to add a new java project in hadoop using eclipse?

Tags: java

As I am doing project in hadoop. I want to know how to add a java project in eclipse plugin in hadoop with steps. And also I wanted to know  how does the output we run as java application will display?

Answer (score 0):

First thing here would be to figure out if there is a eclipse plugin available for your hadoop version installed in your machine. please check if its available here.https://github.com/mkamithkumar/hadoop-eclipse-plugins

If you dont find a compatible version over there then you might need to build your own. please follow the instructions here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yuZ4IjlquPkmC1zXtCeL4GUNKT1uY1xnS_SCBJHps6A/edit?pli=1

Alternatively you could follow instructions over here http://www.techspritz.com/setting-up-eclipse-for-hadoop-development/  (if you have installed Hadoop 1.0.4)